# TableView crashes while making search using search bar during fast typing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

1. I have used fetchedResultsController(FRC) to fetch and list a tableview using fetchedObjects. And the items are listed fine.
2. I am also having a search bar. On typing any string will update the FRC as shown below & perfomFetch() and reload the tableView.

`fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[c] %@, text)`

Everything is working fine, except when I search faster on searchBar. The crash is happening in cellForRowAtIndexPath & numberOfSections saying that the fetchedObjects is 'Empty'

How to resolve the crash due to fast search ?

Comment: put the code here

Comment: Can You give me a full code

Answer (score 1):

If you have used FetchedResultsController's fetchedObjects count property specify the number of rows in section, sometimes your FetchedResultsController's fetchedObject might be nil in such cases app crashes.

try

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0
    }
```

Comment: The code you shared was helpful, and I have resolved it using the section check like following "if (fetchedResultsController.sections?.count)! > section " in 'numberOfRowsInSection' & 'viewForHeaderInSection'. Thank you.